# MATLAB: Convert cell array of 1D strings to 2D string

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell-array

Recent versions of MATLAB have [strings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html), which are N-Dimensional matrices of character vectors.  I have a cell array of such 1D strings that I would like to combine into a single 2D string, but I am having a lot of trouble doing so.  The [`join`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/join.html), [`strjoin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) and [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) functions work on the characters arrays inside the string, and [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html?searchHighlight=cell2mat&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) doesn't work:

```
>> cell2mat({strings(1, 4); strings(1, 4)})
Error using cell2mat (line 52)
CELL2MAT does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.
```

Is there any good way to do this?  I expect the output in the above case to be a 2x1 `string` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` objects behave just like any other datatype (`double`, `char`, etc.) when it comes to concatenation with the same type. As long as you want the result to also be a `string` object, use normal concatenation.

```
result = [strings(1, 4); strings(1, 4)];
```

Or you can use `cat` or `vertcat` to be more explicit

```
result = cat(1, strings(1, 4), strings(1, 4));
result = vertcat(strings(1, 4), strings(1, 4));
```

Alternately you could use indexing to sample the same element twice

```
result = strings([1 1], 4);
```

If your data is already in a cell array, then you can use `{:}` indexing to generate a comma-separated list that you can pass to `cat`

```
C = {string('one'), string('two')};
result = cat(1, C{:})
```

As a side-note, there is no such thing as a 1-dimensional array in MATLAB. All arrays are at least two dimensions (one of which can be 1).

Comment: That is just an example, I have the data in cell format, I don't have the individual strings.